# Is DevExpress MemoEdit Control much heavier than TextEdit?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridControl and i want each cell to be multiline. I have managed to do this by setting the autoheight property and i set ColumnEdit as a MemoEdit control.
And all works perfectly.
My question is : are the MemoEdit Controls i added delays the application more?
Is MemoEdit heavier control versus simply TextEdit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no big difference in terms of performance because DevExpress control engine quite optimized. Also `MemoEdit` very similar to `TextEdit` in implementation.
I implemented grid with 10000 rows with complex controls and custom draw in cells and it works nice.
But if you worrying just create the test data set with thousand rows and check the UI performance.